# Seed function force field to be DateTime2 in Entity Framework MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm using entity framework with MVC

I'm currently in the early development phase so I have a seed function that creates a new database when the model is changed or deleted.

```
public class ImageModelInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ImageModelDBContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ImageModelDBContext context)
    {
        var Images = new List<ImageModel>
        {
            new ImageModel{filename="test.png",
                width=100,
                height=200,
                dateModified=DateTime.Now},
            new ImageModel{filename="test2.png",
                width=200,
                height=400,
                dateModified=DateTime.Now}
        };

        Images.ForEach(i => context.NDEImages.Add(i));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

My problem is the dateModified field is defaulting to DateTime and I want it to be DateTime2. How do I force the seed function to format the field as DateTime2

Comment: Added to this: How does the generator know what format any of the data items should be??

Comment: I haven't tested this but try using `DataTypeAttribute("DateTime2")` see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679311.aspx. Might solve your problem